# How to select a n value in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda data frame looking like this:

```
timestamp            S
2017-04-17 00:00:05  4300
2017-04-17 00:00:10  4297
2017-04-17 00:00:15  4321
2017-04-17 00:00:25  4335
...
2017-04-17 23:59:55  4287
```

If the values of `df['S']` could be seen as abcd, I want to do the following calculation for every row:

```
df['x'] = (df['S'][bcd]/1000)*(10**df['S'][a])
```

so i get:

```
timestamp            S    x
2017-04-17 00:00:05  4300 3000
2017-04-17 00:00:10  4297 2970
2017-04-17 00:00:15  4321 3210
2017-04-17 00:00:25  4335 3350
...
2017-04-17 23:59:55  4287 2870
```

How can I do that?

Comment: what would `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` be in this example? 4, 3, 0, 0 for the first row?

Comment: `df['x'] = (int(str(df['S'])[-3:])/1000)*(10**int(str(df['S'])[0]))` ?

Comment: for the first row it would be 4,3,0,0

Comment: df['x'] = (int(str(df['S'])[-3:])/1000)*(10**int(str(df['S'])[0])) works, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df['x'] = df['S'].astype(str)
df['x'] = (df['x'].str[-3:].astype(int) /1000 * (10**df['x'].str[0].astype(int))).astype(int)
print (df)
                        S     x
timestamp                      
2017-04-17 00:00:05  4300  3000
2017-04-17 00:00:10  4297  2970
2017-04-17 00:00:15  4321  3210
2017-04-17 00:00:25  4335  3350
2017-04-17 23:59:55  4287  2870
```

Comment: Sometimes the value of S can also be below 4000, for example 3900.